# clone a group of svg elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg

I have the following four svg paths tagged within a g element with id="myUniqueID" and class="section113":

```
<svg version="1.1" id="layer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="905.1372px" height="1100px" viewBox="0 300 721.464 889.561" enable-background="new 0 0 721.464 889.561"
 xml:space="preserve">

<g id="myUniqueID" class = "section113" >

 <g id="section113r1"> <path
        23fill:#0000ff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
        d="m 359.6289,535.40475 0.11199,3.61667 34.29601,0 0.11199,-3.62489 z"
        id="section113r1"
        inkscape:connector-curvature="0" /></g>

    <g id="section113r2">   <path
        23fill:#0000ff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.0101289;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
        d="m 359.67072,531.00614 0.11195,4.30938 34.28613,0 0.11195,-4.31918 z"
        id="section113r2"
        inkscape:connector-curvature="0" /></g>

        <g id="section113r3">   <path
        23fill:#0000ff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.00303446;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
        d="m 359.77102,527.12101 0.11198,3.79554 34.29288,0 0.11198,-3.80416 z"
        id="section113r3"
        inkscape:connector-curvature="0" /></g>

            <g id="section113r4">  <path
        23fill:#0000ff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
        d="m 359.58489,523.3875 0.11199,3.66343 34.29602,0 0.11199,-3.67176 z"
        id="section113r4"
        inkscape:connector-curvature="0" /></g>
</g>
```

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bujfd107/3/

I'd like to clone my four paths into the div container with the id="zoombox".

I'm having trouble formatting my code to look like code on this post, so please look into my fiddle to see all the strategies I've already tried (at least 3 different strategies using jquery, and also more with d3).

I'd like the four paths to be cloned into that container, but enlarged by a factor of two, still receptive to tooltip effects like the originals.
Thank youl

Comment: The cloning is easy: `$('#myUniqueID').children().clone().appendTo($('#zoombox'));`, no idea about the resizing

Comment: Hi @Tibrogargan, the cloning was successful, however the cloned SVG elements are invisible. In the Chrome console I can see the elements being appended to the #zoombox div, but they dont appear visibly in the# zoombox div..
Ive changed the z-index of the #zoombox div to 0, but did not work. I've also tried appending the cloned group to the body, but they're still invisible.

Comment: I know very little about SVG sorry, I was reading your question to maybe learn a little more about it.